# Visual Studio 2015 not rendering CSS correctly

Tags: asp.net, templates, visual-studio-2015

I'm building an ASP.net web application using Visual Studio 2015.
For the sake of beauty and aesthetics I tried to use a webpage from a ready made website template as a master page (you know those beautiful responsive templates out there!).

The problem is like this:

- In the design view the master page and all the pages using it don't show correctly, they appear in chaos.
- When testing the design in the browser it shows perfectly well!

What is the reason VS 2015 not able to show the page correctly in the design view?

This is what I tried in pursuit of solving the problem:

- I changed the path to the CSS files (placed ../ and ~) without success.
- I drag-dropped the CSS files into the source view of the master page in order to enable VS to create the links on its own but also without success.

Comment: could you please provide the code that you are testing...

Comment: Do you mean the complete page source?

Comment: yes otherwise how would i know what's going wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sure this would help, I believe this is a problem with VS design view as it happens with many different templates. Anyway, the template is available online, I'm trying it before purchase. Here's the link: http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_3/RTL/index.html

Comment: And now it's not working at all! The Design view is still there but when I click on it nothing happens, it doesn't show the design and remains in the source code view and the program may freeze. This happens even with a new project with a new ASPX page. I reset all the settings of VS but the problem is still there.